# Dynamic query on KnowledgeArticleVersion

Tags: apex, typecast

I see a strange issue that dynamic query does not automatically typecast for knowledgearticleversion object.

Below query works fine:

```
List<Account> lAccount = database.query('Select id from Account');
```

But below query gives error that Incompatible elements for query

```
List<knowledgearticleversion> lAccount = database.query('Select id from knowledgearticleversion');
```

As a workaround i have to use as,

```
List<sobject> lAccount = database.query('Select id from knowledgearticleversion');
```

Why is this happening only for knowlegdearticleversion object? is there a typecasting issue that i am missing?

Comment: I don't get any error with this query.

Comment: thats very strange pepe, i dont understand why the query is failing for me and working in your case. I tried all API versions from 25-30 but still same error for the query. Any reasons u can think of that it gives such results?

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce KnowledgeArticleVersion Object has some unique restrictions as far as querying is concerned. In order to query the object, you must add particular filter queries as a minimum, as this execute anonymous error describes:

[image]

In your query above, you do not have any of the required filters. When I added my own filters to the query, the database.query() method worked for me. Try it out!

PS Seems funny to be answering an error with another error :D

Comment: thanks for response christopher, can u pls post the query which is working for u. I see i have already added the language and Publish status condition. Also below the query which is giving me the error. List<KnowledgeArticleVersion > lAccount = (KnowledgeArticleVersion [])database.query('Select id from KnowledgeArticleVersion where PublishStatus = \'Online\' and language = \'en_US\''); Error is 'Incompatible types since an instance of LIST<SObject> is never an instance of LIST<KnowledgeArticleVersion>'

Comment: Here is my query List<knowledgearticleversion> myUSOnlineKAV = 
    database.query('SELECT publishStatus FROM knowledgearticleversion WHERE PublishStatus=\'Online\' AND Language = \'en_US\'');     That worked for me, so did your query when I ran it through execute anonymous in the developer console. Where are you running your code?

Answer (score 0):

`Database.Query` returns a `SObject[]` so, You need to cast  that assignation like this:

```
= (KnowledgeArticleVersion[])Database.query
```

complete example:

```
List<KnowledgeArticleVersion > lAccount = (KnowledgeArticleVersion [])database.query('Select id from KnowledgeArticleVersion where PublishStatus = \'Online\' and language = \'en_US\'');
```

Giving this log:

> Execute Anonymous: List lAccount =
>   (KnowledgeArticleVersion [])database.query('Select id from
>   KnowledgeArticleVersion where PublishStatus = \'Online\' and language
>   = \'en_US\''); 08:28:52.053 (53852457)|EXECUTION_STARTED 08:28:52.053 (53862241)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
>   08:28:52.054 (54870523)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[1]|Aggregations:0|Select
>   id from KnowledgeArticleVersion where PublishStatus = 'Online' and
>   language = 'en_US' 08:28:52.095
>   (95016258)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[1]|Rows:17

In addition, take in mind that KnowledgeArticleVersion has a SQOL restriction where you must use a `where` clause which includes an `ID` or `PublishStatus and Language` filters.

Comment: martin, issue happens when i try to cast the List<sobject> to List<KnowledgeArticleVersion>. If i try the exact query you mentioned, the error i get is : Save error: Incompatible types since an instance of LIST<SObject> is never an instance of LIST<KnowledgeArticleVersion>

Comment: Dont you get any error when running your query?List<KnowledgeArticleVersion > lAccount = (KnowledgeArticleVersion [])database.query('Select id from KnowledgeArticleVersion where PublishStatus = \'Online\' and language = \'en_US\'');

Comment: No really, take a look of the sample log I've pasted